# How to make PayPal button container transparent

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Title says it all, got no idea how to make this container transparent

I've tried using style == {{"background-color: "transparent"}}, however with no success.
[This is what it looks like as of right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjnkR.png)
Here's my code:

```
          <PayPalScriptProvider options={{"client-id": "myid", components: "buttons", currency: "USD"}} style = {{opacity: 0}}>
            <PayPalButtons createOrder={(data, actions) => {
              return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                    value: globalval
                  }
                }]
              });
            }} style = {{opacity: 0}} onApprove={(data, actions) => {
              return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name); 
              });
            }} />
          </PayPalScriptProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

The buttons render in an iframe and there is no way to reasonably style them as transparent, since the "Debit or Credit Card" button expands form field labels that will have wrong color if made transparent over a dark background (dark text on black)...

[image]

So, *instead* of transparency, what you can do is pad a container around them with a white background.

```
          <div style={{backgroundColor:"white", padding:"5px", borderRadius:"5px"}}>
            <PayPalButtons />
          </div>
```